# OCX registers fine on Windows 8, not so fine on Windows 7

Tags: activex, regsvr32

I have an OCX (ActiveX UI control) written by an external developer. It registers fine using regsvr32 on Windows8 64 bit, but when I run regsvr32 on Windows7 64 bit, I get

```
The module "{module_name}.ocx" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files.

The specified module could not be found.
```

The OCX has no external dependencies. Although it should be saved in SysWow64, I tried it in system32 as well, specifying the complete path.

Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: The error message says it has external dependencies.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see more.

Comment: Actually, Depends helped me more. Found the missing dependency. When people tell you "it has no dependencies", take it with a graint of salt. Thank you.